# Filter entities by String id property in App Engine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have in my model the property:

```
@Id
@Index
public String email;
```

And for filter using `email` variable to search, I have this Filter:

```
Key emailKey = KeyFactory.createKey("email", email);
Filter filter = new 
         FilterPredicate(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY, FilterOperator.EQUAL, emailKey );

result = ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(User.class)
         .filter(filter);
```

Also I try this:

```
result = ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(User.class)
        .filterKey("__key__", email);
```

But neither of them works, any change ?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing object with an string, when you should compare key object with key object.

__key__ is a special property that is of a Key type. This is not a string. If you want launch this filter `.filterKey("__key__", email)` except an email you should provide full key here.

Take a look at **Key filters** section here.

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#filters